# unable to see all the menu options

Tags: interface, settings

[image: look at top left corner]

please advise what do i need to change so i can see my full menu bar. is this a bug? or is it my laptop settings? i have already tried maximizing and minimizing the dialogue box but i still cannot find the menu options.

thanks much!

Comment: hello, could you please precise what options you're talking about?

Comment: Which menu options are you missing? Is it maybe because you're in Object mode instead of Edit mode? If so, just hit Tab to switch between modes.

Comment: *noober* wants to access the main menu. For example, the *File* or *Edit* menu entry. But they are not visible at the moment. -- It's normal that menu and header areas get cut when there is not enough space. But no worries you can scroll the area horizontally with the mouse wheel - or try 2 fingers on the touchpad. The mouse pointer must be in the menu area.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Display resolution under EDIT > Preferences > Interface > Resolution Scale

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you either set your UI's  resolution scale too high (see [Emir's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275231/53447)), or you simply have a screen resolution smaller than the minimum required by Blender.

In any case, it's a small annoyance but easy to deal with: you can scroll any scrollable UI element by dragging it with <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> or rolling <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>. The same thing can happen on any area that is sized too small for the editor's header, so it's a good thing to remember.

Note that you can also resize an area's scale my dragging it with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>.