# Blender doesn't show full menu bar

Tags: interface

I tried to start with blender and installed version 3.3.

But when I start the program I can't see the full (main) menu bar. The first icons I see are *Window* and *Help*, but I can't see *File* icon and others, see screenshot below (https://ibb.co/FzrhDrN).

Does anyone know what I could do?

[image]

Comment: drag with the middle mouse button to right over the menu bar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [interface - unable to see all the menu options - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275224/unable-to-see-all-the-menu-options/275251#275251)